# Why get request works differently in localhost?

Tags: php, get, localhost

If requesting a page from the server or going to another page from current page using hyperlink is considered get request than why this gives an error?

page 1:

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="page2.php?color=red">next page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <?php echo $_GET['color']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: color in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpExcercise\page2.php on line 7

Comment: This might be a caching issue. Delete or disable your browsers cache.

Comment: Might also be the effect of some bad rewriting rule or proxy setup.

Comment: @arkascha well disabling the cache worked.